# Crystal Report not showing the dynamic image when passing the image URL via variable

Tags: c#, .net, image, crystal-reports, report

Im developing a software and the crystal report is acting strange.

I have the follow situation:

I have a image URL from the disk in a variable in C#.
In the report there's a parameter value for the variable.
I have a picture with a formula set in this parameter in the report.

When I set the image URL for the parameter manually, the image shows correctly. Like this:

```
report1.SetParameterValue("pctImage", "D:\PRP System\DB\img1.jpg");
```

But when I use a variable with the same string value (I checked the string value many and many times and it's the same value as the above) the image just doesn't show.

```
string img = "D:\\PRP System\\BD\\modelos\\" + obj1.picture.Replace("D:/PRP System/BD/modelos/", "");
report1.SetParameterValue("pctImage", img);
```

Obj1 has the URL for the image with the name of it.

I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head try this

```
string img = @"D:\PRP System\BD\modelos\" + obj1.picture.Replace("D:/PRP System/BD/modelos/", "");
```

The string `D:\\PRP System\\BD\modelos\\` will be sent ti CR like that and that is not a valid path

Comment: well could you in CR report drag the parameter on the report just to see what value you get. Then perhaps we could find the problem ?

Comment: report1.SetParameterValue("pctImage", "D:\PRP System\DB\img1.jpg"); this line can't be right the path is an invalid string.

Comment: Ivan, It was report1.SetParameterValue("pctImage", "D:\\PRP System\\DB\\img1.jpg");